# Can a x32 application utilize a x64 database?

Tags: c#, windows, postgresql

While working with tech support at a company-that-shall-not-be-named, a tech stated the following to me:

> PROGRAM_NAME is currently x32, so it cannot use x64 drivers. We are
>   working on an x64 release at the moment, but we have lots of testing
>   to do first.

The x64 drivers he is referencing are for Postgres 64 bit database. And the database is running on a x64 windows 7 box. It is registered as ODBC datasource.

As far as I know, if I were to write a 32 bit application, let's say in C# just as an example, that my application would connect without issue to a 64 bit database. Because of this, the tech's reply seems suspicious to me.

Is it really true that a x32 application cannot use a x64 database?

Comment: I don't think it should matter. The drivers are just wrappers around native code which has to be 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: Sounds more like his application is linking with the wrong ODBC drivers (a 32-bit app linking with 64-bit native libs or vice-versa).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the error.

This has nothing to do with the bitness of the database server; it's about the bitness of the *ODBC driver*.

ODBC drivers are loaded in-process, so they must match the bitness of your process.

None of the client code (your own code or the driver) knows or cares about the bitness of the database server.

Comment: Let's see if I am following you correctly: let's hypothetically say that I have a x64 database, but I register it using a x32 OBDC driver, would then my x32 application be able to load the x32 OBDC driver, and then in turn be able to utilize a x64 database?

Answer (score 1):

What the tech said is:

> PROGRAM_NAME is currently x32, so it cannot use x64 **drivers**

and he's correct for it since a driver is usually provided as dynamic library, and you can't mix bitness between the calling application and the dynamic library.

However, this doesn't mean you can't connect to a 64-bit dbms from a 32-bit application. The communication is commonly done through socket, which doesn't care about the bitness of the client and server, as long as both agree about the protocol implementation.